# Makefile error: recipe commences before first target

Tags: bash, makefile

Trying to wrap my head around this seemingly trivial error:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
    
.ONESHELL:
    
aaa = 1
    
ifeq (1,0)
    
test:
    @if [ "asd" == "123" ]; then
        echo "true"
    else
        echo "false"
    fi

endif
```

I get the error at the "else" statement: `Makefile:13: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.`

It looks like it's treating the else as part of the above `ifeq (1,0)` line. If I remove line 5 (`aaa = 1`) it works fine. Why does it behave like this?

***EDIT:***
The picture below also shows the characters used:
[image]

***EDIT2:*** This is the output from cat

```
$ cat -A Makefile
SHELL = /bin/bash$
$
.ONESHELL:$
$
aaa = 1$
$
ifeq (1,0)$
$
test:$
^I@if [ "asd" == "123" ]; then$
^I^Iecho "true"$
^Ielse$
^I^Iecho "false"$
^Ifi$
$
endif
```

Comment: Probably you don't have a hard TAB character indenting all the lines of your recipe.  Also note that `.ONESHELL` was added in GNU make 3.82 so be sure you have that version or newer.

Comment: I tested this with make 4.1, 4,2 and 4.3 and the result is the same. I also made sure to have a hard TAB character.

Comment: That shows what the file looks like in your editor.  It's not uncommon for programming editors (that don't have special modes for makefiles) to convert tabs to spaces when saving files.  You need to check the file that was saved to see what it contains.  I'm very, very sure it won't have TABs.  You can use `cat -t Makefile` to see the contents of the file: it should contain `^I` as the first thing on the recipe lines, to show that they start with TAB.

Comment: I know this is hard to believe but they are all TABs. I added a picture above with the `cat -A Makefile` command. You can also test this for yourself as it is a very simple example.

Comment: You're right.  That's a bug.  It will be annoying to fix, though, because it will require make parsing all the content in the non-taken branch of the if-statement so it can determine whether the `else` is part of a recipe or not.  At the moment make ignores all the content of the non-taken branch.  Please file this at Savannah: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=make

Comment: You can work around this by putting the else as part of the previous line, even though you use `.ONESHELL`: change `echo "true"\n\telse` to `echo "true"; \\n\telse`.  That's probably why we haven't seen that issue: it can only really happen in `.ONESHELL` situations.

Comment: Ok, this is good (and scary) to know. But why does moving the `aaa = 1` assignment above `.ONESHELL:` also removes the error? Also, I changed the GNU specific `.RECIPEPREFIX` to another character and this also gets rid of the error.

Comment: Moving the `aaa = 1` fixes it because the `.ONESHELL` feature doesn't actually take effect until make starts to read the NEXT command; until that happens make is trying to read a recipe for the `.ONESHELL` target.  Since the contents of the if-statement are ignored that doesn't count as starting the next command.  If you put the assignment after `.ONESHELL` make knows that the `.ONESHELL` target is complete and it enables the `.ONESHELL` feature.

Comment: For `.RECIPEPREFIX`, it doesn't get rid of the error (at least not in my testing).  However you do get a _different_ error: because the `^I^Iecho "false"` no longer starts with the recipe prefix you won't get a _recipe commences before first target_ because make doesn't recognize these lines as recipe lines.  Instead, I get `missing separator` because `echo "false"` is not a valid make command.

Comment: Even more scary is to consider if you put the `.RECIPEPREFIX` setting _inside_ the if-statement then prefix the `else` with that recipe prefix... in order to handle this correctly make would have to really process all aspects of the non-taken branch, including settings of `.RECIPEPREFIX`, then just ignore it instead of adding it to the database.  That's really unfortunate, and may be impossible, because some people use if-statements to contain completely invalid make content which make can't parse: that works fine today.  Ouch.